# Im not sure I fully understand babel's ordering with passPerPreset

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

So currently Im having a problem with `transform-runtime` changing `exports * from ...` into `import` statements.

This is fixed with the following configuration.

```
passPerPreset          : true,
cacheDirectory         : true,
plugins                : ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
presets: [
  {
    plugins            : ['transform-runtime'],
  },
  {
    passPerPreset      : false,
    presets            : ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
  },
]
```

My understanding is that passPerPreset runs each preset individually so when it gets to a node it will run the `transform-runtime` and then the next time it will run the set of presets at the bottom. This solve the issue because the first pass picks up all the `export *`s changes them into `import`s then on the next pass `es2015` will convert these to require statements.

Now my question comes with the `transform-decorators-legacy` is that being run on both passes in its current position? If my above explination is correct then why can't I have it as a sibling to `transform-runtime` like:

```
passPerPreset          : true,
cacheDirectory         : true,
presets: [
  {
    plugins            : ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-runtime'],
  },
  {
    passPerPreset      : false,
    presets            : ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
  },
]
```

Thanks for any help. Im just trying to understand babel in more depth.